# Revert to original CSS state in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to get my jQuery code to, when I hover over one of my elements (.pdf), change the font color of another element (.dl) to blue, and then when I stop hovering over my first element (.pdf) the second element goes back to its original color.

I managed to get this to work, but I also have to have another jQuery code which when I hover over the second element (.dl), my first element (.pdf) goes blue, and then returns to its original state when the hover ends on my second element (.dl).

The issue I'm having is when I load the page, if I hover over my first element (.pdf), (.dl) becomes blue and when I stop hovering it returns to white, but when I hover over (.dl) after adding the jQuery that does the .pdf hover, (.dl) stays white!

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".pdf").hover(function (f) {
        $(".dl a").css('color', '#33b5e5');
    },
    function (f) {
        $(".dl a").css('color', '#fff');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".dl").hover(function (g) {
        $(".pdfasdf").show();
        (".dl").show();
    },
    function (g) {
        $(".pdfasdf").hide();
        (".dl").hide();
    });
});
```

(bit messy, sorry! I'm new!)

and the relevant CSS in my jfiddle:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48bQN/)

I basically just need to know if there's a way to revert to the original CSS state in jQuery. I believe the (.dl a:hover) is being overridden by the jQuery that tells it to become white when not hovering over .pdf.

**Edit** I was able to get it to work by adding an `!important` after my .dl a:hover font color in my CSS, but I'd still like to know if there's a jQuery way to do this, as my way is quite sloppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using jQuery's `.addClass(classname)` and `.removeClass(classname)`.

Documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

This way, you can just toggle the class and not have to worry about a specific CSS state.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/dW7ur/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to revert the css parameter to its original value use the `.css(propertyName, value)` method with an empty `value`:

```
$(".dl a").css('color', '');
```

Example:

```js
var changed = false;

setInterval(function() {
  if (changed) {
    $("#container").css("text-align", "");
  } else {
    $("#container").css("text-align", "right");
  }

  changed = !changed;

}, 1000);
```

```css
#container {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  Text
</div>
```

Same example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v4h1spqL/

This is described in jQuery's [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value):

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. `$( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" )` — removes that property from an element
> if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style
> attribute, through jQuery's `.css()` method, or through direct DOM
> manipulation of the `style` property.